# why does find always return two rows?

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

i have two rows in database

```
[
  Anime {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Kimi ',
    synopsis: 'Perangn berakhir?',
    metaDescription: 'Kuma Ku online',
    coverLink: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/antaraksi/image/upload/v1607682688/1VtaTXsHTRfh8m49OVJfMb4JVuh_e0hy3g.jpg',
    slug: 'kimi-to-boku-no-saigo-no-senjou-aruiwa-sekai-ga-hajimaru-seisen',
    view: 8,
    episodes: []
  },
  Anime {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Hajimaru Seisen1',
    synopsis: 'berakhir?1',
    metaDescription: 'Kuma Kuma Kuma Ba Kuma Bear free, Kuma Kuma Kuma Bear online1',
    coverLink: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/antaraksi/image/upload/v1607682688/1VtaTXsHTRfh8m49OVJfMb4JVuh_e0hy3g.jpg',
    slug: 'kimi-to-boku-no-saigo-no-senjou-aruiwa-sekai-ga-hajimaru-seisen-1',
    view: 2,
    episodes: []
  }
]
```

i want to find one by the slug.

```
  async findOne(slug: string) {
    const findOptions = {
      slug,
      relations: ['episodes']
    }
    const anime = await this.animesRepository.find(findOptions);
    console.log(anime);
    return anime;
  }
```

but it always return two rows. the slug column is `text` in the database. how can i find one by the slug?

Comment: You can use limit operator to get only 1 records.
Something like this:-
`db.collection.find(condition).limit(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method `findOone` to get one row, you can do something like:

```
const user = await this.animesRepository.findOne({
 relations: ['episodes'],
 where: slug
});
```

Comment: yes. It works after change the slug object